# Localization of a fiber ring. ${(B\otimes_A \kappa(\mathfrak{p}))}_\mathfrak{r} = B_\mathfrak{q}\otimes_A \kappa(\mathfrak{p})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A, B$ be commutative rings, $f\colon A\to B$ be  a ring homomorphism and $\mathfrak{p} \in \rm{Spec}A$. Consider a ring $C= B\otimes_A \kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ and the canonical map $B\to C$, where $\kappa(\mathfrak{p}) = A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$ is a residue field of $\mathfrak{p}$. Is it true that $$C_\mathfrak{r} = B_\mathfrak{q}\otimes_A \kappa(\mathfrak{p})$$ for arbitrary $\mathfrak{r} \in \rm{Spec} C$ and $\mathfrak{q} = \mathfrak{r} \cap B$ ?

This equation is written on Matsumura's book, Commutative Algebra (Japanese version). I tried to prove this by constructing the canonical isomorphism between the two. Since the tensor product of rings is pushout in the category of rings, existence of the map $B_\mathfrak{q}\otimes_A \kappa(\mathfrak{p}) \to C_\mathfrak{r}$ is easy. I tried to make the map $C_\mathfrak{r} \to B_\mathfrak{q}\otimes_A \kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ from the universal property of localization, but I couldn't prove the elements of $C\setminus \mathfrak{r}$ are invertible in $ B_\mathfrak{q}\otimes_A \kappa(\mathfrak{p})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE.

Let $ x=\sum (b_i\otimes [\frac{a_i}{r_i}])\not\in $. We Assume that $\tilde x=\sum (\frac{b_i}{1}\otimes [\frac{a_i}{r_i}])$  is not invertible in ⊗() and reach a contradiction.

Put $r = \prod r_i \in A\setminus p\ ,\ r'_i=\prod_{j\not=i}r_j $ then: 
$$(1\otimes [\frac{r}{1}])\tilde x= (\sum \frac{f(a_ir_i')b_i}{1}\otimes [\frac{1}{1}])$$ Is not invertible in  ⊗() as well (here we use commutativity).

Therefore $\sum f(a_ir_i')b_i\in q$ which implies $(\sum f(a_ir_i')b_i\otimes [\frac{1}{1}])\in $  but then:
$$x=(1\otimes [\frac{1}{r}])(\sum f(a_ir_i')b_i\otimes [\frac{1}{1}])\in $$  contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! It seems nice to me.

Comment: I think $a$ is typo of $a_i$ ? I wonder if there's a more "natural" or "intuitive" proof for the isomorphism (without difficult calculation).

Comment: Thank you, corrected. If you think of something more natural please write it here, would be nice to find something like that.